# Pattern matching with lists and strings with Prolog

Tags: prolog

a prolog newby here.

I found the following code online:

```
string_to_list_of_characters(String, Characters) :-
     name(String, Xs),
     maplist( number_to_character,
        Xs, Characters ).
number_to_character(Number, Character) :-
     name(Character, [Number]).
```

I want to use it to do some pattern matching.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
wordH1(H1) :-
    word(H1),
    string_length(H1,6),
    string_to_list_of_characters(H1, X) = a,_,_,_,_,_.
```

I want to get all strings which are of length 6 and that start with an a.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using some very old learning resource. Instead of writing this `string_to_list_of_characters` predicate yourself you can just use the builtin `atom_chars`:

```
?- atom_chars(apple, Chars).
Chars = [a, p, p, l, e].

?- atom_chars(amazon, Chars).
Chars = [a, m, a, z, o, n].
```

For pattern matching you can write lists similarly to how you tried to do it, but you need square brackets around the elements. You also don't pattern match on something like a "function application expression" as you would in other programming languages. Rather you apply a predicate and then write a separate unification. So it's not something like `atom_chars(A, B) = Something` but rather:

```
?- atom_chars(apple, Chars), Chars = [a,_,_,_,_,_].
false.

?- atom_chars(amazon, Chars), Chars = [a,_,_,_,_,_].
Chars = [a, m, a, z, o, n].
```

Comment: Thank you, I've written a bit more code. `cross_words(H1,H2,V1,V2) :-
    word(H1),
    word(H2),
    word(V1),
    word(V2),
 word(H2) \= word(V2),
 word(H1) \= word(V1),
 string_length(H1,6),
    string_length(H2,5),
    string_length(V1,4),
    string_length(V2,5).` What I want to do, is to use atom_char to match for example, the third letter of H1 to the fourth letter of V1. Can I use it within the  program file? I think what you are suggesting is to write atom_char ... in the terminal. Is that correct?

Comment: You can use `atom_chars` in your definitions in your program file, yes.